# Same list can be used, but is still empty

Tags: c#, list

I'm using a list to display drawing elements on a bitmap.

```
public void Teken(Graphics gr)
{
   gr.DrawImage(this.bitmap, 0, 0);
   foreach (Element e in this.tekenelementen)
      e.teken(gr);
}
```

The elements on the bitmap are being drawn just fine by saying:

```
rechthoek r = new rechthoek(//parameters here);
tekenelementen.add(r);
```

Now I'm trying to use the same list for File I/O.

```
public void SlaOpTekst()
{
   SaveFileDialog opslagdialoog = new SaveFileDialog();
   opslagdialoog.Filter = "txt-bestand|*.txt";
   if (opslagdialoog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(opslagdialoog.FileName);
      this.tekenelementen.ForEach(sw.WriteLine);     //still has to be extended
      sw.Close();
   }
}
```

Somehow, whenever I'm saving it to a txt-file (and no, it's not the output, I've tried many different ways of output and all come back empty, except the Count-property which gives a '0'), the file comes back empty. Does anyone know why, and how to fix it?

Comment: sw.writeline needs parameters to write, all you are doing is writing an empty line.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx
Check the function examples on msdn.

Comment: That isn't the answer. I've tried something similar before and have now tried
foreach (Element e in this.tekenelementen)
                        sw.WriteLine("element");
But that didn't work.

Comment: Well what is this takenelement class you need to provide additional information if it has support to be stringified.

Post the class code, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.tekenelementen.ForEach(t => sw.WriteLine(t.ToString()); //change to appropriate method/property.
```

Comment: No, didn't work. I tried some different combinations too, but they didn't budge.

Comment: Are you sure there are elements in your collection? If the size of the collection is 0 that would indicate no elements are present in tekenelementen